# How do I write header to a csv file with data

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to write header along with data under it to a csv file. This is what I have.

```
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as data:
        headers = ['Server', 'IP']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(data, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n', fieldnames=headers)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow({'Server': str(serv_list), 'IP': ip_addr})
```

I am getting the serv_list and ip_addr from a txt file. The above code writes the header after every entry. If I use 'a' (append), it replaces the data each time. I have also tried the code below but same results.

```
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as data:
    writer = csv.writer(data)
    writer.writerow(["Server", "IP"])
    writer.writerow([str(serv_list), ip_addr])
```

Comment: Quick guess: is this in a file/function you call several times? If so, every call will add the header line again.

Comment: Yes, it is running in a for loop. Each time it gets the name of the server and IP address. I would like it to be able to write to csv each time without adding the header over and over again.

Comment: Calling that in a loop will be very inefficient: every time, it has to find the file again, open it again, write to it, close it again. You should open the file before entering the loop, and only have the writerow part within the loop.

Comment: I did that but the issue remains. It writes the header over and over again before each server and ip address

Comment: Please edit your question with the updated code including both the loop and the opening of the file ^^